# Function in C that counts how many times a character read appears in a string

Tags: c, character, codeblocks

I'm using CodeBlocks and C as a programming language. I need to make a function that counts how many times a character read appears in a string (also read).
Line 8 error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int find(char s, char ch, int l)
{
    int i, j=0;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(s[i],ch)==0)
        j++;
}
return j;
}
int main()
{
    char s[30];
    int i,j,l;
    char ch;

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(s);
    l = strlen(s)+1;
    printf("Enter the character: ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    j=find(s, ch, l);
    printf("\n%c occurs %d times",ch,j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` isn't the same as `char[]`, read your textbook about arrays again.

Comment: Aside: please don't use `l` as a variable name. Is that a `1`? It is clear in `int l;` but not in `i<l`. Also please get out of the habit of starting the output with newline, that should be the last character output.

Comment: Please note **all** of the "warnings" you get from compiling this code and understand that you need to resolve each and every one of them.

Comment: Just as a side note: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)

Answer (score 2):

Your error was that in the function declaration you didn't mention that s was an array. You needed to use s[] and there was no need for strcmp function in the if statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int find(char s[], char ch, int l)
{
    int i, j=0;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
{
    if(s[i] == ch)
        j++;
}
return j;
}
int main()
{
    char s[30];
    int i,j,l;
    char ch;

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(s);
    l = strlen(s)+1;
    printf("Enter the character: ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    j=find(s, ch, l);
    printf("\n%c occurs %d times",ch,j);
    return 0;
}
```